# Notation of Subrepresentation

Tags: representation-theory

Sorry, I have a stupid question about the notation in Representation Theory.
In the image below, what does the highlighted term mean?
I've understood that $\rho(g)$ is a matrix representing the element $g \in G$ in the vector space $V$. But I can't get what $(W)$ is doing there.

[image]

### Reference

- https://www.imperial.ac.uk/people/t.schedler/document/4881/Lecture1/?Lecture1.pdf

Comment: $\rho(g)W:=\{\rho(g)w\mid w\in W\}$

Comment: Oh, I see.... very simple... 
Thanks!!

Comment: No, $\rho(g)$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$ (not a matrix), and $\rho(g)(W)$ is the usual [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Image_of_a_subset) of $W$ under $\rho(g)$.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood the whole thing.... after watching some Youtube videos, now it's getting clear!!
Thanks!