# Notation of representation in representation theory

Tags: representation-theory

Sorry, I have a stupid question about the notation in Representation Theory.

In the image below, does the highlighted part mean a vector $\rho(g)(v) \in V$?
Because $\rho(g) \in V$ is a representation of the element $g \in G$ in the vector space $V$, right?

[image]

### Reference

- https://www.imperial.ac.uk/people/t.schedler/document/4881/Lecture1/?Lecture1.pdf

Comment: They mean $W={\rm span}\{\rho(g)v\mid g\in G\}$ where $\rho(g)v$ is the result of the linear operator $\rho(g)$ applied to the vector $v$.

Comment: $\rho(g) \notin V$, $\rho(g)$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$, and the evaluation of $\rho(g)$ at some vector $v \in V$ is denoted by $\rho(g)(v)$.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the correction! As discussed in [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273200/notation-of-subrepresentation?noredirect=1#comment8891705_4273200), the confusion is getting clear after reviewing some materials!

Comment: sorry, can you help me with interpreting the connection of sentences in the next line, too?
I don't get the connection of $\rho(h) \sum_{g \in G} a_g \rho(g) v = \sum_{g \in G} a_g \rho(hg) v$ and the subrepresentation? What's incorporating $h$ in $\rho(hg)$ got to with the subrepresentation?

Comment: It's used to prove $W$ is closed under the application of $\rho(h)$s, which is the definition of being a subrepresentation.

Comment: Got it, Thank you!!